# Find $q(x) \in \Bbb{Q}[x] $ such that $f(a)$ is its zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $p(x) \in \Bbb{Q}[x] $ and $a \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $p(a)=0$. Find $q(x) \in \Bbb{Q}[x] $ such that $f(a)$ is its zero, where
$p(x) =x^3 - 9x - 3$ and $f(a)=a^2-2 $.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: What is $Q$, please?

Comment: Perhaps "\Bbb{Q}", "$\Bbb{Q}$"?

Comment: If it really stands for $\Bbb Q$ there would be nothing to prove as $p$ doesn't have a root in $\Bbb Q$. On the other hand if $Q$ is an arbitrary field the statement would also be completely trivial as we may take $q(x)=x-f(a)$. So probably $a$ should be contained only in some extension field of $Q$ (and whether $Q$ is the field of rational numbers or not should then not really matter for the rest of the exercise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $a$ is a root of $p$, so $a^3-9a-3=0$. This is equivalent to

$$a(a^2-9)-3=0\Leftrightarrow a(a^2-2-7)-3=0\Leftrightarrow a(f(a)-7)-3=0$$

so $f(a)$ is a root of $q(x)=ax-7a-3=0$. Since $a\in Q$, we can guarantee that $q(x)\in Q[x]$.